# Week count issue using the TimePeriod library (CodeProject)

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, .net-2.0

I am just trying to make use of this [TimePeriod](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) library. I just found something which I'm not sure is correct, yet I'm not able to flag it as a bug. Just need a clarification.

```
Dim xDateDiff As New DateDiff(New Date(2011, 1, 1), New Date(2011, 2, 1))
Console.WriteLine("Week Count : " + xDateDiff.Weeks().ToString()
```

Now the week count is outputting 5, where as there are, if you see the Gregorian calendar, 6 weeks between the two dates. Is the week count zero-based? This is what is troubling me.

Please help.

Comment: You could post that as an answer and then I can just provide you some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used the TimePeriod library, but isn't it just that there is a 5-week difference between two dates, but there are 6 weeks if you include the first week? My point is, couldn't you just do `xDateDiff.Weeks() + 1`?

Answer (score 1):

The **DateDiff** class was designed to represent UI friendly differences of two dates. The **Week** property counts only the completed weeks.

In case to calculate the involved count of weeks between two dates, you can use the following code:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void InvolvedWeekCount()
{
  Console.WriteLine( "Involved week count: " +
    CalcInvolvedWeekCount( new DateTime( 2011, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2011, 1, 2 ), DayOfWeek.Sunday ) );
  // > Involved week count: 2
  Console.WriteLine( "Involved week count: " +
    CalcInvolvedWeekCount( new DateTime( 2011, 1, 2 ), new DateTime( 2011, 1, 8 ), DayOfWeek.Sunday ) );
  // > Involved week count: 1
  Console.WriteLine( "Involved week count: " +
    CalcInvolvedWeekCount( new DateTime( 2011, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2011, 1, 29 ), DayOfWeek.Sunday ) );
  // > Involved week count: 5
  Console.WriteLine( "Involved week count: " +
    CalcInvolvedWeekCount( new DateTime( 2011, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2011, 1, 30 ), DayOfWeek.Sunday ) );
  // > Involved week count: 6
  Console.WriteLine( "Involved week count: " +
    CalcInvolvedWeekCount( new DateTime( 2011, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2011, 2, 1 ), DayOfWeek.Sunday ) );
  // > Involved week count: 6
} // InvolvedWeekCount

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
private int CalcInvolvedWeekCount( DateTime date1, DateTime date2, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek )
{
  if ( date1.Date.Equals( date2.Date ) )
  {
    return 0;
  }

  DateTime startWeek = TimeTool.GetStartOfWeek( date1, firstDayOfWeek );
  DateTime endWeek = TimeTool.GetStartOfWeek( date2, firstDayOfWeek ).AddDays( TimeSpec.DaysPerWeek );

  return (int)( endWeek.Subtract( startWeek ).TotalDays / TimeSpec.DaysPerWeek );
} // CalcInvolvedWeekCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question assumes a falsehood.  Feb 1 comes 31 days after Jan 1.  31/7 is just under four and a half, so Feb 1 falls in the fifth week after Jan 1.  How do you come up with 6 as the expected answer?

Comment: Please check the calendar given in the link - [January 2011](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=2011&month=1&country=35) . Please turn on week count in the calendar and you will see there are six weeks, including incomplete ones also. Another way to check is if you see there are six vertical row. And each row has to be considered one week as I'm considering `Sunday` to be the start of the week.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see what you mean.  In that case, the answer seems to be that you are using the wrong tool for the job: the Weeks () method of the DateDiff class does not implement the logic you desire.

Comment: Please guide me to a good tool that just returns this value. Or may be some functions which does the same will also do(will be a better option).